# Updating column zIndex on legendItem mouseover/mouseout in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I have a chart where one of the series provided is a 'total' sum value of the other values.

What I'm trying to is to have this column initially behind the others (or hidden) then bring it to the front when that series' `legendItem` is hovered.

So far I've been able to increase the `zIndex` on the series to bring the 'total' column to the front on 'mouseover' no problem, but triggering the inverse on 'mouseout' isn't working for me and the 'total' column stays in front.

I've also tried a simlar solution using `.toFront()`, this worked but was left with the same problem of moving the column back BEHIND on mouseout.

How might I correctly move this column to front/back on legendItem hover?

https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-night-9p0gk?file=/src/components/BarChart.vue:1272-1325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 'mouseout' you can call `toFront` method on the stacked series only:

```
chart.series.forEach(s => {
    if (s.name === 'Total') {
        s.legendItem.on('mouseover', () => {
            s.group.toFront();
        });

        s.legendItem.on('mouseout', () => {
            s.chart.series.forEach(item => {
                if (s !== item) {
                    item.group.toFront();
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mpduxwkh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#toFront